# Hiding the child menu content of the parent when another parent is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am unable to hide the child menu of the current parent when i tried to click on another parent. I needed to hide the child menu corresponding to the previous parent when another parent is clicked. At present, my code is displaying the previous parent children in addition to the current parent children.

```js
//loads the children corresponding to the parent

<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php'; 

$cat = array();
if(!empty($_POST))
{   
}
elseif(!empty($_GET)) {   
    if($_GET['feat']== 'getchild')
    { 
        if(!empty($_GET['c_id']))
        {
        $sql = "select a.category, a.category_id from cscart_category_descriptions a join cscart_categories b where a.category_id=b.        category_id and b.parent_id={$_GET['c_id']} and status='A'"; 
        $res = get_data_form_db($sql);
        
        foreach($res as $ob) 
        {
        $html.='<li><span id = "list'.$ob['category_id'].'"  onclick = "LinkClick(\''.$ob['category_id'].'\')" valu        e="'.$ob['category_id'].'">'.$ob['category'].'</span></li>';
        }
            
        if($html!='')
        {
        $html = "<ul>$html</ul>";
        }    
        echo $html;

        }    
        }    
        }
        else {
        echo "invalid type request";
        exit;
        }

function get_data_form_db($query)
{
        if(!empty($query))
        {
            //echo $query;
            $Result = mysql_query($query);
            //var_dump($Result);
            $i  = -1; 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
            {
                $rows[++$i] = $row;
            }
        }    
    return $rows;
}
?>
```

```html
// ajax_index.php
// This file is used to load the parent from the database //and makes an ajax call to load its child.
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php'; 
?>
<html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
   <h1>Categories and sub Categories</h1>
   <?php
   $Result = mysql_query("select cd.category, cd.category_id from cscart_category_descriptions cd, cscart_categories cs where cd.category_id = cs.category_id and cs.parent_id = 0 and status ='A';");
    
    while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
    {
        $c_id[++$i] = $Row[1];
        $categories[$Row[1]] = $Row[0];
    }
    $c_id[0] = $i;
    
    for($i=0; $i < $c_id[0]; $i++)
    {
        echo '<li><span  onclick = "LinkClick(\''.$c_id[$i].'\')" >'.$categories[$c_id[$i]].'</span><span id = "list'.$c_id[$i].'"></span></li>';
        
    
    }
    
?>
   
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var Clicked = {};
        var Previous = null;
        function LinkClick(id)
        {
            console.log(id);

            if(Clicked[id] == 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            Clicked[id] = 1;
                        
            $.ajax({ 
                type:'GET',
                url: "test.php",
                data:{feat:"getchild", c_id:id},
                success:function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    $("#list"+id).append(result);
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
        
        </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You will need to modify some code like...
    <span id = "list'.$c_id[$i].'" class="submenu"></span>

   Also you will to modify js code like...

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Clicked = {};
    var Previous = null;
    function LinkClick(id)
    {
        console.log(id);

        if(Clicked[id] == 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Clicked[id] = 1;
        $(".submenu").html('');            
        $.ajax({ 
            type:'GET',
            url: "test.php",
            data:{feat:"getchild", c_id:id},
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
                $("#list"+id).append(result);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Please can you be more specific about the changes.

Comment: <span id = "list'.$c_id[$i].'" class="submenu"></span>   We have added class   "submenu" into child menu span.  If i click parent menu. child class "submenu" will empty.  like code $(".submenu").html('');

Comment: I wanted to hide the children at the same level when another of its siblings is clicked, but what you suggested is only working at one-level not at multiple level moreover its working only for the 1st click on any of the content.

Comment: It will work on one-level only. do you want to work on multi-level?

Comment: Yes, because some of the parents had children, which also had their children, and so on.

Comment: suggestion : why are you not using this menu?  https://codyhouse.co/demo/multi-level-accordion-menu/index.html    .    so many menu are available on online.    http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Accordion%20menu/

Comment: Ya, but it would be great if you can modify this.

Comment: $html.='<li><span  onclick = "LinkClick(\''.$ob['category_id'].'\')" value="'.$ob['category_id'].'">'.$ob['category'].'</span><span id = "list'.$ob['category_id'].'" class="submenu"></span></li>';     Can you update some code on ajax file.